# SQL Sub Query to find data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all titles of films that have greater replacement cost than some R rating film.

film table has...

```
film_id, title, description, release_year, language_id, original_language_id, rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, special_features, last_update
```

This is not working...

```
SELECT
    title
FROM film
WHERE replacement_cost > (SELECT
    replacement_cost
FROM film
WHERE rating = 'R');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title
FROM film
WHERE replacement_cost >
    (SELECT MAX(replacement_cost)
     FROM film
      WHERE rating = 'R');
```

You need aggregation of some kind to make the subselect a scalar value.  Using MAX() in your query would give you the highest replacement_cost of a rated R film.

To get the replacement_cost of a particular film then you need to do the same thing but modify your where statement to be the film you want.  say you know the film_id then you could do:

```
SELECT title
FROM film
WHERE replacement_cost >
    (SELECT replacement_cost
     FROM film
      WHERE film_id = 123);
```

Note I took off MAX() because when using the primary key or criteria that will choose a single scalar value (1 column 1 row) from the table you don't actually have to use aggregation.